# DROP Table taking lot of time in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

We have a database with tables which have encrypted data and are having clustered column store indexes with a 1000 fixed partitions. All tables have same structure. Encrypted columns are of type Varbinary.

I need to provide the database with subset of the tables in previous database.

For this we are taking a backup, restoring, find which tables are not necessary.
and Drop those tables.

Each table is of around 200 MB after compression.

Issue is that, the DROP table is taking a lot of time. Few tables are taking 3-4 secs to drop. But some tables are taking 20 minutes to drop this is causing a lot of time. For dropping 1000 tables it is taking more than 18 hours.

The Machine we are using is a very high configuration 128 GB RAM with 16 Cores all available to SQL Server.

We tried ways like disabling clustered columnar index, truncate table before dropping but it did not help. We are dropping the tables in batches, even that is not helping. 
Also we cannot merge partitions as the tables which needs to stay are going to use the same scheme.

This is not a Admin activity, we are providing export in .mdf format. And for this we are following two approaches, for smaller set of data to be moved, we create empty DB and write/insert required records, and when large part has to be moved, we are doing backup restore and drop not required tables.

We need to understand why is it taking so much time. Can you help us.

Comment: Please clarify: a) when you `DROP TABLE` - there are user connections to database or b) `DROP TABLE` takes a lot of time even without connections  to the database?

Comment: Dropping 1000 tables is a pretty good sign you might want to take a different approach. How many tables are left? Maybe you need to create a new database and then copy in only the tables you want. Are you doing these drops in a transaction? Because would cause this to crawl like a snail as tempdb explodes into hundreds of GB. We need a LOT more information here before a realistic answer can be discovered.

Comment: @Alex: Yes there is only one connection to the DB. But still drop table statement takes lot of time.

Comment: We are dropping 20 tables each in a batch, so temp db is fine. no issues.

Comment: Look for blocking queries and schema locks that are preventing your drop to finish.

Comment: Use `sp_who2` to see what is going on. A truncate and delete performance is affected by foreign keys but I don't know what would impact a table DROP